# What is arbitrary code execution (ACE) and how does it affect speedrunning?

Tags: terminology, speedrun

There has been a lot of records being set in The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time within the last couple of weeks or so. A lot of these records keep stating that "ACE" is the reason for this. I have read that "ACE" stands for Arbitrary Code Execution, but why is ACE all of sudden now setting incredible records?

From an article I've read ACE can be described as...

> This means that the game can be forced to load and execute a save file
>   name as if it is game code — so using a save file name that is game
>   code can access parts of the game left over from its development and
>   testing.

So basically within a series of in-game inputs, you can use a filename in order to run some development code left over?

Comment: Comments were deleted. This section is not to discuss the validity of glitches in speedruns, or what counts as beating a game.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Arbitrary Code Execution (ACE) is a glitch that allows the player to cause the instruction pointer to jump to a section of memory that can be written to by the player (such as the filename, the angle and position of certain actors, controller inputs, etc). When the instruction pointer enters this section of memory, it runs that portion of memory as code.

In other words, it allows the player to write "code" with regular input and execute it in game.

The most obvious speedrunning application is to write and run code that tells the game to run the end credits, [as we see in the OoT any% speedrun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHxgji9WHLI), but that's certainly not the only one; in Ocarina of Time 100% No Source Requirement, [ACE is used to give Link almost every item](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItFJKZaYsYo). ACE is usually only allowed in the any% category, which does limit applications permitted by the rules.

Ocarina of Time is not the only game with ACE. For example, Super Mario World also uses ACE in its [any% speedrun, writing code using sprite coordinate data to run the end credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkQdwUns7H8) (more commonly known as "credits warp"). It can also be used to [write and run an entire game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hB6eY73sLV0).

---

This is not to be confused with other memory manipulation glitches. For instance, Super Mario World's [Cloud Glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXH1Gtv9aFw) abuses the fact that Bowser's "time remaining until next fight cycle" timer and the cloud's x coordinate share a register, since they were never meant to appear in the same room together. Since the instruction pointer remains within the normal range, you're not running any arbitrary code here even though you are manipulating the game's behavior by abusing this shared memory.

Comment: also ACE was discovered in MM recently https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb9yijgukak

Comment: The most well known application of this is the Missingno glitch in Pokemon Red, where you duplicate the 6th item in your bag by performing a series of specific actions.

Comment: See also [Reach the Credits from Kokiri Forest using ACE (Ocarina of Time Glitch Explained)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdRJWDKb5Bo).

Comment: It should be mentioned that Arbitrary Code Execution does not only exist in videogames, but also other programs, such as web servers. And as you might imagine, random strangers being able to do whatever they want on your server is *really bad*.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I don't think the MissingNo. glitch qualifies as *arbitrary* code execution. If it was an ACE exploit, it would permit players (usually with emulator tooling) to do literally anything they want with the game, such as in [this video for Pokémon Yellow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vjm8P8utT5g). The specific actions you perform to get MissingNo. aren't really "code" that gets "run"; they're in-game behaviors that happen to touch on an edge case not accounted for, where the game's original code misinterprets data already in the ROM to modify unexpected RAM addresses.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Joe Sewell beat me to it; my reaction was "That's not arbitrary code execution!" There are bugs in Pokémon, some of them even abuse shared memory locations where previous actions cause certain values to reside in memory locations which mean something different in another context. The bug that lets you catch mew (or anything at all, really) without using any gameshark or game genie, capturable by normal gameplay, is another example of this. In fact, if I recall, you can even set its stats if you do it right. Not ACE, but sort of similar I suppose.

Comment: Matrix analogy:  things like Missingno are like the spoon boy  -- you can take advantage of the coding of the system and manipulate it (bend the spoon).  ACE is like being Neo, where you can remake the whole world at will.

Comment: @eps I always thought it was a fourth wall break. The boy tells Neo - and the audience - that he should see the truth. The spoon isn't real, it's fake, it's CGI.

Comment: An atypical but very evocative example is the [ACE in Super Mario Land 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h15Jk6MOgP0). In this case the player glitches Mario out bounds of the map, and the game world reflects the memory he's in, each block corresponding to one memory cell, block type representing the value. Mario must navigate through memory cells with non-obstructing values in ROM area, to reach the RAM, then find the one block responsible for starting end credits and break it.

Comment: It's not a typical ACE because you're not able to create arbitrary code that does anything you want - you may only modify cells Mario can interact with, can't spawn any arbitrary blocks - but it's evocative - helpful in understanding how ACE works, the 1:1 correspondence between blocks of the game world and the system memory, and how breaking a specific block has a specific effect, helps understanding how regular ACE turns sprite positions or controller angles into executable data.

Answer (score 19):

*I'm not 100% sure about the inner workings of various assemblers and processors, but I'm attempting as best as I can to explain, how I understand it*

Let's say the machine instructions to perform a map transition / warp is some value, for example `AC`.
Let's say, this instruction takes a value to decide where to warp the player. For example, the final boss room has value `C8`.

**So if you tell your game to call the routine to execute `AC C8`, it knows that it should teleport the player to the final boss.**

Now, assume you have some inventory mechanism that saves items by their id. A bomb has id `C8` and a stick has id `AC`.
Assume the data for the inventory is laid out sequentially, so having a stick first and then a bomb is represented as `AC C8` as well.

Now "all you need to do" is to trick the program into jumping to a wrong location while it tries to execute some kind of action. This is usually done by the "program counter" which points to the address of the instruction to execute.

If you manage to manipulate the program counter to point to the start of your inventory instead of the address it normally *should* point to, the program will now read the data from your inventory, **but treats it as executable code instead**. So since your inventory contains "stick, bomb" the data that will be read is `AC C8`, which causes the program to warp you to the boss room now.

I think something like this is usually achieved by corrupting parts of the memory or somthing similar. The section of memory that is corrupted contains "nonsensical" data now, but can still be executed.

I'd say, a good example of how all of this can be exploited is shown here: [How to beat Pokemon Yellow in 0:00](https://youtu.be/OyhEKG_g53o)

Comment: Well this was a good explanation. One thing to note is buffer overflow exploits are notorious for causing arbitrary code execution.

Comment: I think this answer is brilliant - a person completely unfamiliar with progamming might completely understand it.  You may want to expand on what the "program counter" actually is to make the answer even better.

Comment: I expect the SRM ACE glitch (in OoT) works by causing the game to accidentally overwrite the location of some code (stored in RAM), with an arbitrary location you can select. Then when it wants to run that code, it runs the wrong code by mistake, and the code it runs is the code which you set up earlier.